# Photo rotated in custom camera application

Tags: android, camera, rotation, photo

My app is using camera to take photos. The problem is, the photo is rotated by  90 degrees. The app is designed to run in portrait orientation and I have set

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

to avoid orientation changes. I thought I managed to fix it with

```
parameters.setRotation(90);
```

but it turns out that it varies on different devices (tested on lenovo ThinkPad tablet and a copule of smartphones). I tried reading the EXIF of the photo but orientation is not included there. I know there are many similar posts but most of them regards default camera app. Could someone explain me what this problem is caused by and how can i fix it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for getting image as u wanted

public static Bitmap createRotatedBitmap(Bitmap bm, float degree) {

Bitmap bitmap = null;

if (degree != 0) {

Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

matrix.preRotate(degree);

bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, bm.getWidth(),

```
bm.getHeight(), matrix, true);
```

}

return bitmap;

}

bitmap = createRotatedBitmap(bitmap, 90);

Comment: But how do I detect if I should rotate the image? On some devices the photo is rotated properly...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, orientation will not be exactly same for all the devices. It is completely hardware dependent, can vary device to device. You can't fix it, only one option you have just allow user to set the rotation once your application launched at first time get the base rotation angle and save it in to the settings and then give your functionality afterwards.

Comment: But wait, there are apps (e.g. instagram) that use custom camera and works well on various devices. There has to be a way to fix it.